# why is negative margin set to visually hidden text for screen readers?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wcag

My question is about *IR(Image Replacement)* for screen readers.

I learned that The `.blind` code below is the best technique to hide text visually while providing information for screen readers. but I don't know the need for a few codes.

HTML

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <span class="blind">hidden_alt_text</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.wrap {
    background: url(test.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.blind {
    position: absolute;

    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;

    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**1. why is `margin: -1px` set to that?**

I heard that `margin: -1px` is better than `top: -1, left: -1` for performance. But basically why are we trying to raise this up in the left-top direction.

**2. why is `width 1, height 1` set to that?**

The reason is that screen readers can't read that the height and width are zero. But I think there's already text in the tag, so the height and width are not zero! Why are we setting it up again?

**3. Should negative margins not be used?**

I've found some [discussion](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1985). they said it is not good to set negative margin. but I couldn't find any errors they have met. 'NVDA' screen reader read it in the right order. How should I accept this discussion?

Comment: The point of the CSS code is to hide it from people with no visual impairment (people who can see the image and read it), but allow screen readers to access the text and read it. Of course, this whole thing misses the actual best method, which is using actual text, not images of text, in HTML. Modern CSS allows us to manipulate text in increasingly interesting ways that obviate the need for most uses of image replacement.

Comment: Some screen readers also use CSS to determine if the contents is visible and should be considered. It might as of that be a hack to trick a certain reader in thinking that the text is visible, but still hiding it. In general, the recommended way is to use ARIA attributes anyway. `<div class="wrap" role="img" aria-label="hidden_alt_text">`

Answer (score 1):

**1. why is `margin: -1px` set to that?**

I was unable to find a *good* reason for why this property is used in this technique. Some variations of this technique on [accessibility websites](https://a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content/) do not use the `margin` property.

I've seen some mentions that it may have been a workaround for older browsers, but I cannot definitively confirm that.

In my own testing, I could not find any issues by removing it.

I suspect that the use of the `margin` property may be a leftover from a hybrid approach of this approach and the technique of [using absolute positioning to move the text off-screen](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#techniques). I've attempted to illustrate how negative margins would be used in a situation like this in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vgLrt84/1/). The dimensions have been scaled up from 1px to 100px to better illustrate how it works.

Typically, in this approach, you would make the containing element 1px height/width, because setting it to 0px height/width means that it won't be read by screen readers. Just imagine that `div.wrap` is the 1px that you can't get rid of.

With the advent of `clip` and `clip-path`, I suspect that `overflow:hidden` became more of a fallback for legacy browsers that was included in the technique.

It doesn't matter which direction you use to position the text off-screen. You could go top, right, or bottom. Bottom is typically avoided because that's the direction pages grow as more content is added, and that would make it a moving target.

**2. why is `width 1, height 1` set to that?**

As you said in your question, screen readers can't read elements where the height and width are zero, so people go with the next best thing, which is 1px height/width.

> But I think there's already text in the tag, so the height and width are not zero! Why are we setting it up again?

When you set a CSS `width` and `height` property, those values override whatever the default height and width (based on content size) would be. Without any values specified, the width of a block-level element (like a paragraph) will always be 100% of the parent container. Setting a CSS `width` value of `1px` means that it really will be only `1px` wide.

**3. Should negative margins not be used?**

It's your call, but I wouldn't recommend using the CSS `clip` property because it's been [deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-css-masking-1-20140826/#propdef-clip).

I would recommend continuing to use [absolute positioning to move the text off-screen](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#techniques). It works quite well, it's cross-browser compatible, and I see no reason to go with anything else.

```
.hidden {
  position:absolute;
  left:-10000px;
  top:auto;
  width:1px;
  height:1px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Avoid too big value like `left: -10000px;`. It can make VoiceOver Safari+iOS to lag. `left: -2px;` is sufficient.

Comment: In absolute positioning. the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties specify offsets from the edges of the element's containing block. So, if the element has a parent container that's not `body`, then a value of `-2px` probably won't work.

Comment: (edited) @Josh I know that the (negative) margin attribute only moves the location, can I have more explanation for that ( _to make the content effectively 0px in height/width_ )?

Comment: I edited my answer to better explain. Since there's no historical record of these things, I've had to speculate more than I would like in an answer like this. Hope that this is helpful.

Comment: If -2px isn't sufficient, -100px or -200px would be perfectly OK, but -10000px is clearly exagerated.
Try with -1000000px, you will see that VO hesitates a few seconds.
Note that `opacity: 0` is also present as another variation.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't necessarily need to be any certain value. That said, there are now monitors on the market that have resolutions like 7680 x 4320, Given those numbers (and the fact that more 8K and beyond models will follow), 10000px isn't too out of line, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer for question 3

@Josh has answered points 1 and 2 well, however on point 3 he is not quite right.

Some screen readers will not read items in the correct order. If you use negative margin (even by -1px), there is a chance they will not picked up in the correct place, as can be seen in [this discussion on negative margin](https://github.com/h5bp/main.css/issues/12).

Below is an adaptation we currently use, based on widely accepted patterns.

### A quick explanation of the properties for a robust visually hidden class:

- `border: 0;` - remove any borders (not needed really, is for edge cases)
- `padding: 0;` - remove padding (not needed really, is for edge cases)
- `margin: 0;` - remove margin
- `position: absolute !important;` - use absolute positioning so we can use `clip`
- `height: 1px;` - make as small as possible, 0 would not work as is the same as `display: none`
- `width: 1px` - same as `height: 1px;`
- `overflow: hidden` - we don't want any text etc. spilling out.
- `clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);` - for IE 6 and 7 as that was the syntax then.
- `clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);` - modern browsers (as of today supported by the biggest ones)
- `clip-path: inset(50%);` - left unprefixed as by the time `clip` gets removed browsers will have implemented `clip-path` as it is the replacement. We still need `clip` for IE. [Clip is also very widely supported today](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_clip). `inset(50%)` is used as that insets the clip path by 50% from each corner, making a o height and width clip box.
- `white-space: nowrap;` - this is important, some screen readers [do not treat Line Feeds as spaces](https://medium.com/@jessebeach/beware-smushed-off-screen-accessible-text-5952a4c2cbfe) so the words get 'smushed' together.

### The final class I currently use, updated to use `clip-path`.

```
.visually-hidden { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 - a 0 height clip, off to the bottom right of the visible 1px box */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); /*maybe deprecated but we need to support legacy browsers */
    clip-path: inset(50%); /*modern browsers, clip-path works inwards from each corner*/
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line to stop words getting smushed together (as they go onto seperate lines and some screen readers do not understand line feeds as a space */
}
```

### Additional thoughts

Don't name the class '.blind', someone may take offence at that, hehe.

I settled on `.vh`, short for `.visually-hidden`, as I was typing it 100 times a day. Either that or you could call it `.sr-only` as it is mainly for screen readers as they do in Bootstrap.

**Also you mentioned you were using it for Image Replacement. Is there a reason you aren't using the `alt` tag for that? This is far easier to maintain and has the added benefit that if your image doesn't load the `alt` text will be displayed.**

### Update from comments

@Josh wanted a better example but all I could find were more bug reports as this appears to be a low priority bug fix.

Hopefully the below is sufficient for everyone to see the problem with negative margin.

As I couldn't find any articles on this and just lots of bug reports, I have added an example that I found that I was able to replicate the problem on.

Try it in **VoiceOver on Chrome**, then remove the `margin: -1px` and try again.

You will see it is read correctly the second time without the negative margin.

```css
.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute!important;
    margin: -1px!important;
    border: 0!important;
    padding: 0!important;
    width: 1px!important;
    height: 1px!important;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0)!important;
    text-transform: none!important;
    white-space: nowrap!important;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Strange text ordering</h2>
<p>Each of these links should read out as "Show more 1 2":</p>
<a href="#">
  Show more
  <span class="visually-hidden">
    1
  </span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">
    2
  </span>
</a>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <span>Show more</span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">
    1
  </span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">
    2
  </span>
</a>
<a href="#">
  Show
  <span>
    more
  </span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">
    1
  </span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">
    2
  </span>
</a>
<p>They read out as expected in NVDA and JAWS, but the order changes in VoiceOver.</p>
<p><strong>Test environment:</strong> macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.3, using VoiceOver with Safari Version 11.0.3 (13604.5.6) and Chrome Version 64.0.3282.167</p>
```

Also [here is another codepen with a variation that has the same issue](https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/OjpqxL)

#### Why not just use `aria-label` and be done with this madness?

The reason this is a 'low priority fix' is because the recommended way of providing extra information is to use `aria-label`.

The reason you may want to reconsider this is that [`aria-label` only has around a 75% reliability (scroll to `aria-label` section)](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/).

**Visually hidden text is the best method we have at the moment, but adding a negative margin will cause issues as the above snippet and linked CodePen illustrate.**

Comment: Do you have a justification for why using the clip method is better than positioning the text off screen? I read through the "discussion on negative margin" that you posted, and the whole thing seems to be people trying to get that technique to work correctly.

Comment: Yes, reading order can be affected, I will see if I can reference something that is more clear.

Comment: GrahamRitchie -- Yes, please do. I've never seen anything saying that CSS positioning text off screen will affect reading order. Everything should be read in the order that it appears in the DOM, and CSS can't change the DOM.

Comment: Added some extra to the answer and 2 examples for you to try. Couldn't find a good article on it just lots of different bug reports. Give the examples a go with Chrome and VoiceOver, the problem still persists today it seems.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie could you explain why setting 1 value is better than other big ones? I'm confused because there is the clip attribute, so nothing can be seen on the screen, those width/height values don't seem to matter if they're bigger than 0. Is it good in terms of performance? if so, could you explain it?

Comment: Think of it like multiple fallbacks. Certain items don't accept the `clip` property properly (bugs in browsers) so we make the square as small as possible in case the `clip` doesn't work. At the end of the day the whole thing is a hack so you have to account for multiple edge cases (like the negative margin point). There is no need to worry about performance (except for the negative margin part) as you will never render enough visually hidden content to slow a page down. If you do then you really have done something wrong.